# Custom multiplication operation between variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I am constructing polynomial expressions in the variables $s[0],s[1],...,s[n]$ and I'm trying to define a new operation to simplify the expression:

```
$Assumptions = B \[Element] Complexes
newTimes[] := 1
newTimes[a_] := a
newTimes[s[0], b_] := b
newTimes[a_, s[0]] := a
newTimes[a___, newTimes[b_, c__], d___] := newTimes[a, b, c, d];
newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer]*s[j_Integer], d___] := newTimes[a, newTimes[s[i], s[j]], d];
newTimes[a___, x_ + y_, b___] := newTimes[a, x, b] + newTimes[a, y, b];
newTimes[a___, K_Complex*s[i_Integer], b___] := K*newTimes[a, s[i], b];
newTimes[a___, K_Complex, b___] := K*newTimes[a, b];
(*B a complex valued variable*)
newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer], s[i_Integer], b___] := B*newTimes[a, s[i], b];
newTimes[a___, K_Complex*s[i_Integer], b___] := K*newTimes[a, s[i], b];

newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer], s[i_Integer + 1], s[i_Integer], b___] := 
  newTimes[a, s[i], b];
newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer], s[i_Integer - 1], s[i_Integer], b___] := 
  newTimes[a, s[i], b];
newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer], s[j_Integer], b___] /; 
   TrueQ[Abs[i - j] > 1] := newTimes[a, s[j]*s[i], b];
newTimes[a___, s[i_Integer], s[j_Integer], b___] /; 
   TrueQ[Abs[i - j] < 2] := newTimes[a, s[i]*s[j], b];
```

I have seen one way to apply this using fold:

```
expr = Sum[s[j], {j, 0, 2}]
Expand[Fold[newTimes[#1, #2] &, expr, Table[expr, {1}]]]
```

My questions:

**How can I apply this to an already built polynomial?** For example $s[0]+3s[1]s[4]-s[1]s[0]s[2]$ and then I want to apply newTimes anywhere their is a multiplication of the variables.

**How do I recognize and pull out coefficients with different formats (fractions, etc.)**?

For example this line will only pull out a constant if the expression is: $K*s[i]$ but won't recognize $\frac{-s[i]}{K}$

```
newTimes[a___, K_Complex*s[i_Integer], b___] := K*newTimes[a, s[i], b];
```

Comment: You might need to add more definitions for the forms you want; to see what those are, check out, for example `-s[i]/K // FullForm`. Note that currently that line only accounts for multiplication by a single number, but `-s[i]/K` involves multiplication by two numbers. You also might want to consider giving `newTimes` the attributes `Orderless` (commutative) and `Flat` (associative), which help with pattern matching and mean you don't need to worry about writing those defs by hand so much!

Comment: Note also that heads like `Complex` are more akin to data types here. So for example,  `-1` does not match the pattern `_Complex` because it's an `Integer`. You might want the pattern `K_?NumericQ` or `K_?(Element[#, Complexes] &)
` instead.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks. Although in this case newTimes isn't commutative

Comment: Ah, gotcha. (Note that `Times` is `Orderless`, though, so the expression `s[1]*s[0]*s[2]` will automatically be reordered to `s[0]*s[1]*s[2]` unless you `Hold` the expression, if your already-built polynomials use `Times`—not sure if they do, though.)

Comment: I can't get K_?NumericQ or K_?(Element[#, Complexes] &) to work. Mathematica doesn't seem to recognize these in the same way as _Integer or _Complex. In this case I know that the coefficients will be some functions of the variable B

Comment: I thought of looking for the variables instead so (K_ /; (! MemberQ[vars, K])) seems to work. (I think the above just needed parenthesis to work also)